# Import properties of file/strip and set render correctly (resolution and fps)

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor

When drag-and-dropping video files into sequencer, render FPS is automatically set correctly.

I want to import a file through python script and do the same. Also for resolution width/height.

This is a script so far.

Newbie, <3 Blender.

```
import bpy
import os

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.sequence_editor_create()
seq = scene.sequence_editor.sequences
fp = "/path-to-movie-file.mp4"
name = os.path.basename(fp)
channel = 0
frame_start = 1

ms = seq.new_movie(
    name = name,
    filepath = fp,
    channel = channel,
    frame_start = frame_start
)
scene.frame_end = ms.frame_final_duration
print(ms)
strip = scene.sequence_editor.active_strip

#scene.render.fps = strip.fps
#scene.render.resolution_x = ms.resolution_x
#scene.render.resolution_y = ms.resolution_y
```

Comment: bpy.ops.sequencer.rendersize() Set render size and aspect from active sequence

Comment: The trouble is that Blender is lazy loading the strip resolution(don't ask me why), which means that the playhead needs to be over the clip and show it in Preview, before the resolution can be detected. 

Alternatively, I once coded a script to copy the source properties to the render preferences. It's using Media Info to extract the data: https://github.com/tin2tin/MediaInfoExtractor

Comment: @susu: I don't get how to activate the sequence through script.
tintwotin: I "feel" it should be able to be done without additional plugins. Nice music for the video!